# How to manage updates of WPF app with Visual Studio Installer

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer

I have WPF application who is possible to update when is have new version. For create installer I will use Visual Studio Installer. I understand how to auto update my app, but this is not exactly what I want.

I want when user check is want to "Automatically check for updates" only then is check do is have new updates. Like in the picture

[image]

My question is: Is it possible with Visual Studio Installer to manage update for application. When user is checked then if is possible to update to new version. If user not checked then the application is not check for new version.

Im sorry for my bad English. Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear whether you want that checkbox in the installer itself or in the app. All the instances I've seen are in the app. There's no point in putting the check in the installer because the user does that just once, and updates may be generated after the product has been installed. You cannot run the same install again! So this check is added to the app, and the implementations I've built do a web service call to the company web site (passing in the installed product's version, ProductCode, UpgradeCode) and if there is an update the app downloads it. The user may or may not be able to install the upgrade if it requires elevated privilege and the user has limited privileges.

The supported upgrade mechanism with VS setups is to increment the setup project's version property, accept the requested changes, rebuild the entire MSI with incremented file versions for the files you need updating, and set RemovePreviousVersions to true to upgrade the entire product.